# Why can't my Spring MVC view load my WAR file's resource?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web

I have a Java/Spring web application.

Controller code that shows the view looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "showmessage/{messageId}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView viewMessage(Model model,  @PathVariable("messageId") Integer messageId) throws Exception {
    /* do stuff */
    return new ModelAndView("show-message","message",message);
}
```

Which displays the contents of the `show-message.jsp` file.

The problem is, the `show-message.jsp` file is trying to load resources that are in the `myapp.WAR` file ... for example ...

```
/resources/dist/js/jquery/jquery-validate-1.17.0/jquery.validate.js
```

The browser reports that it failed to load this from this URL ...

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/showmessage/resources/dist/js/jquery/jquery-validate-1.17.0/jquery.validate.js
```

... because the resource is actually here ...

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/resources/dist/js/jquery/jquery-validate-1.17.0/jquery.validate.js
```

If I change the resource line in the JSP from "resources/dist/..." to SLASH "/resources/dist/..." is still doesn't work because it tries load this ...

```
http://localhost:8080/resources/dist/js/jquery/jquery-validate-1.17.0/jquery.validate.js
```

... and fails.

What's wrong with my app and how do I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you JSP you are most likely using a relative `href` values e.g.:

```
<scripts src="resources/dist/js/jquery/jquery-validate-1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

The browser will resolve it against the current URL which is `showmessage/{messageId}` based on your `@RequestMapping` annotation.

Try specifying an absolute URL to your script. Since you have JSP you can use [<c:url>](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/javaserver-pages-3rd/0596005636/re39.html).

```
<scripts src="<c:url value="/resources/dist/js/jquery/jquery-validate-1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"/>"></script>
```

Comment: Hi ... when I use a relative value ex: "resources/..." it looks for the resources relative to the requested url ... ex: http://localhost:8080/myapp/showmessage/resources/..."  -- when I use an absolute value ex: "/resources/..." it looks for the resource in the root of the server ... ex: http://localhost:8080/resources/..." -- how do I get it to look for the resource in the correct location ... ex: http://localhost:8080/myapp/resources/..." ?

Comment: Use something that will output the correct URL containing current contextPath. You are using JSP so you have JSTL e.g. <c:url> as per my example.

Comment: @RobertHume, you could try this `<script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/dist/js/jquery/jquery-validate-1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>`. `<c:url>` should do the same stuff basically.

Comment: Hi all -- I used @Ivan solution and it worked -- thanks for helping me figure it out!!